# Problems with the modality of a JDialog (mouse events for main window both fired and buffered)

Tags: java, swing, events, modal-dialog, jcombobox

I made a JDialog and the modality works presumably fine

```
dialog.setModalityType(JDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

But then my problem is:

- I´m throwing Jdialog after a jcombobox.setSelection() and I need to click twice in Accept button in order to hide the dialog, because dropdown popup is consuming the first click for closing himself. I fixed it by manually calling jcombobox.hidePopup() before calling the dialog, but I cannot understand if the later is modal, why the mouse events trigger things outside the window?`
- My Main window buffers somehow the mouse events, so for those mouse events which are not activated when the modal dialog is drawn (as happens with the previous point), it seems they get buffered and are applied after dialog closure. Is this an expected behavior?

Thank u!

Comment: What if you delay the showing of the JDialog by queuing it on the event thread by calling it inside a Runnable with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- replace `jcombobox.hidePopup("doesn't make me sence")` with `ActionListener` or `ItemListener` added to the `JComboBox`
- add [RequestFocusListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) by @camickr for setting the `FocusOwner` correctly
- for why reasons are there another `MouseListeners`, maybe in the case that fird any events to the `JComponents` that you can't to set `Focus` correctly

Comment: I´m really sorry, I dont understand correctly points 1 and 3. For the first: replace hidepopup with a listener? u mean unregistering the listeners? (indeed I already did it). For the third, is not the other MouseListeners,  is that default components (table cells) selection events and this gets execute after closing the modal. But thanks for the second one